# Logstash filter according to fields source declare in filebeat config

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

[image: Filebeat log config using fielsd]

```
 input {


 beats
  {
 port => 5042

 }
 }



output {





    if [source] == "access"
{
        elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["16.113.56.102:9200"]
    index => "logstsh-access-nginxlogs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}

else if [source] == "error"
 {

 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["16.113.56.102:9200"]
    index => "logstsh-error-nginxlogs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }


}       
}
```

I would like to separate the log file using the fields source and that declared at filebeat input, for the, from kibana side, the log have the source either is access/error, however, the logstash won't pass the log to elastic search, I'm wondering is it the right way to declare the source? I try to use the absolute in the input part, it works like a charm, so I think the issues is with the input filebeat or logstash.

Comment: For filter part, I will just leave it blank for now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you use one **output** if you don't need to send the data to multiple elasticsearch clusters. For example:

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["16.113.56.102:9200"]
    index => "logstash-%{source}-nginxlogs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }       
}
```

In filebeat, you can add fields into **each documents** with the **processor**

```
processors:
  - add_fields:
      target: project
      fields:
        name: myproject
        id: '574734885120952459'
```

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/add-fields.html

Note: to understand if the problem because of Logstash you can use the following method.

[Why are the logs not indexed in the elasticsearch logstash structure I designed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74809830/why-are-the-logs-not-indexed-in-the-elasticsearch-logstash-structure-i-designed/74813918#74813918)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I have some questions ya, the reason why that I use two output is actually I would like to separate the nginx access log and error log to different filebeat index for the ease of analysing the data, because I not able to use the absolute path since the log to remote server,

Comment: Okay, how can I help you?

Comment: I double checked the logstash part, there nothing wrong with it if I only use one output that read directory from the directory, may I know there if there anyway to separate the access log and error log into different filebeat index because I will multiple access log file and error log file, I try to make all access/ error become one filebeat index and push to kibana. Exp: nginx-access-log-2023/02/02 and nginx-error-log-2023/02/02