# logstash does not load data to elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have created an index in elasticsearch to store some test logs, but I can't get the data to load from logstash.
I create the index in ES:

```json
    put sonicwall
    {
      "mappings":{
        "properties":{
          "Time": { "type":"text"},
          "Category": { "type":"text"},
          "Group": { "type":"text"},
          "Event":{ "type":"text"},
          "Priority":{ "type":"text"}
        }
      }
    }
```

The index is created
[image]

Now, my logstash config file:

```rb
    input{
        file{
            path => "C:/Elastic/logsPrueba/log3.csv"
            start_position => beginning
        }
    }
    filter{
        csv{
            separator => ","
            columns => ["Time","Category","Group","Event","Priority"]
        }
        
    }
    output{
        
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "sonicwall"
        }
        stdout {}
    }
```

This is the CSV

[image]

when I run logstash, the data is never loaded
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure you are waiting long enough ? How about you only use the `stdout` output for now ? I could test your config on my end and it works fine.

Comment: I have tried with only stdout on the output but the result is the same, it shows nothing. And I wait a long time.
 Is it possible that logstash cannot read the file?

Comment: Maybe enable debug logging ? `log.level: debug` in your logstahs.yml

Comment: I did it, but there were so many messages and it is very difficult to find something useful. I also set the ERROR level, but there are no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have discovered the problem. When the csv file is read for the first time, some kind of record is saved at the end of the file and then logstash is not able to start from the beginning. I have tried to fix it with sincedb_path = "NULL" on Windows or sincedb_path="/dev/null" on Linux, but logstash is able to start reading the file from the beginning again and again.
If I add a new log line and run logstash, only the newly added line is painted.

Comment: In windows, you must put "NUL" with a single L. Now I can always read the file from the beginning.
I also recommend deleting the contents of the logstash folder. This is where the sincedb pointers are stored.

Answer (score 0):

check the stats from logstash events to understand where is the problem.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9600/_node/stats/events?pretty'
```

[image]
[Why are the logs not indexed in the elasticsearch logstash structure I designed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74809830/why-are-the-logs-not-indexed-in-the-elasticsearch-logstash-structure-i-designed/74813918#74813918)

Comment: I am using version 8.7 on Windows. From power shell and cmd it does not let me enter that command. I have tried to put it in the kibana dev tools but it doesn't know what events is, only get /_nodes/stats